# Can I use gradient operator on both sides of an equation?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, convex-optimization

By first order approximation of Taylor series and finding the value of a function at x around y:

$f(x) \geq f(y) + \nabla f(y)^{T} (x-y)$

Can I do this:

$||\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)|| \geq || \nabla^2 f(y) ^{T} (x-y)||$

if $f$ is a convex function.

Comment: The action of operating twice with the gradient operator is not a Laplacian, as that is the divergence ($\nabla \cdot$) of a gradient ($\nabla f$). The action of operating twice with the gradient operator is the *vector Laplacian* (or the Hessian) $\nabla^2 \mathbf{\Phi} = (\nabla^2 \Phi_x, \nabla^2 \Phi_y, \nabla^2 \Phi_z)$ for some Vector field $\Phi$

Comment: Yes you are right. But can I do this under my assumption of f being a convex. Or may be its holds for any f until its smooth?